# ImportError: cannot import name 'CsrfProtect' from 'flask_wtf.csrf'

Tags: python, flask

I've been working my way through updates to fix all the dependencies in my python program...and now I'm getting this error even though it doesn't seem that I should.  Here are the relevant details:

**requirements.txt file**

```
Flask-WTF==1.0.1
```

**extensions.py file**

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CsrfProtect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager

debug_toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension()
mail = Mail()
csrf = CsrfProtect()
db = SQLAlchemy()
login_manager = LoginManager()
```

**Error trace**

```
website_1   |   File "/smartcowz/smartcowz/blueprints/user/models.py", line 17, in <module>
website_1   |     from lib.util_sqlalchemy import ResourceMixin, AwareDateTime
website_1   |   File "/smartcowz/lib/util_sqlalchemy.py", line 7, in <module>
website_1   |     from smartcowz.extensions import db
website_1   |   File "/smartcowz/smartcowz/extensions.py", line 5, in <module>
website_1   |     from flask_wtf.csrf import CsrfProtect
website_1   | ImportError: cannot import name 'CsrfProtect' from 'flask_wtf.csrf'   
(/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py)
```

changed import call from `wtf` to `wtf.csrf` but didn't help.  Looking for guidance where I don't have to go to lower version as that just puts me in a loop with other dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve by changing the following:

csrf = CsrfProtect()

to:

csrf = CSRFProtect()

Worked previously, but stopped after updating python and other dependencies within my app...